# Webdriver: I am not able to automate slider

Tags: java, webdriver

I am trying to automate slider by using Action class but getting following error.

What I have tried:

```
public void slideTheBar() {
    WebElement slider = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.sliderA div#slider_minmax_maxKnobA"));
    Actions move = new Actions(driver);
    Action action = move.dragAndDropBy(slider, 30, 0).build();
    action.perform();
}
```

Error :

> $Proxy22 cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.internal.Locatable

Please let me know if someone can help me with this.

For example : the slider we see in any media player to increase the volume in which click on  one point then drag and drop to desired point.

FYI : webdriver version is 2.24.1

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in second line, when you type "Action action = move.dragAndDropBy(slider, 30, 0).build();"

In the above line, the first word Action should be typed as Actions, then it will work, please see my code,

Thread.sleep(4000);
        try{
        WebElement slider=GlobalVars.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all']"));
                Actions move =new Actions(GlobalVars.driver);
        Actions action=move.dragAndDropBy(slider, 60, 0);
        action.perform();}
        catch(Exception e){
            e.getMessage();

If you still have any queries , please let me know.

Thanks

Regards